# how to convert nested dictionaries in multiplex socket to pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, binance

I am attempting to convert these nested dictionaries into DataFrames. I have scoured the web for more information on this but cannot find much on this particular situation. The issue I continue to run into is a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error after attempting to convert using json.loads().

This is the coroutine I have to receive multiple sockets data so far.

```
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()

    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ms = bm.multiplex_socket(['ltcusdt@kline_1m', 'btcusdt@kline_1m'])
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ms as mscm:
        while True:
            res = await mscm.recv()
            print(res)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output comes as nested dictionaries in which I would like to acquire only kline pricing data (nested dictionary as "k") and format it to pandas dataframes and store in HDF5 file as well as directly to Postgres Database where I currently have OHLCV tables created.

```
{'stream': 'btcusdt@kline_1m', 'data': {'e': 'kline', 'E': 1627406952750, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1627406940000, 'T': 1627406999999, 's': 'BTCUSDT', 'i': '1m', 'f': 972731799, 'L': 972733284, 'o': '37761.23000000', 'c': '37753.06000000', 'h': '37761.24000000', 'l': '37745.74000000', 'v': '5.29347800', 'n': 1486, 'x': False, 'q': '199846.18941298', 'V': '1.87072500', 'Q': '70625.81836987', 'B': '0'}}}
{'stream': 'ltcusdt@kline_1m', 'data': {'e': 'kline', 'E': 1627406953532, 's': 'LTCUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1627406940000, 'T': 1627406999999, 's': 'LTCUSDT', 'i': '1m', 'f': 185284307, 'L': 185284315, 'o': '132.45000000', 'c': '132.41000000', 'h': '132.45000000', 'l': '132.40000000', 'v': '22.23228000', 'n': 9, 'x': False, 'q': '2944.17206090', 'V': '3.11654000', 'Q': '412.66106140', 'B': '0'}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.json_normalize(k)`?

Comment: No I have not. Actually I was having trouble defining the keys in the the dictionaries in the first place as I am still fairly new to programming in general. But, pd.json_normalize(res) helped me create the DataFrame I needed! I believe from here I can drop and rename the columns as I need. Thanks a bunch!